# Apply hash pattern to polygon in openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, polygon

I am creating a vector layer comprised of polygons from a KML file using Openlayers and I need to apply a "hash" pattern (diagonal striping) to the polygons.  I know Openlayers doesn't natively support adding a background image to a polygon in a vector layer but I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to accomplish this?  The styling of a vector polygon appears to be limited to solid colors and opacity.  If need be I'll extend OpenLayers to add this functionality in by manually drawing the hash lines within the polygon boundaries but I'm hoping someone has a simpler suggestion before I head down that road.

Comment: Do you mean styling polygon borders (exterior) or internal polygon ?

Comment: @Myra - internal polygon

Comment: I was going to say,polygon has only outer boundary stroke style as hash,but currently no support for internal style except for color & opacity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using SLD this can now be done. Not sure if it's in version 2.11 or the trunk development but i saw the [addition was committed](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/changeset/12393) about 6 months ago.

It uses an `ExternalGraphic` so you can set an image of whatever pattern or color you want.

Here's the **[Example](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/ossipoff/openlayers/examples/graphicfill.html)**

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the response and linking to the example - that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have not try this yet, but I have similar problem. 
 
The solution I will try is svg pattern. 

OpenLayers has  SVG.js which is used to draw polygons. I will modify that to support patterns.

 Look Image -->
http://i2.aijaa.com/b/00653/9707550.jpg

In this example i have modified http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/behavior-fixed-http-gml.html example to demonstrate pattern usage. --> Could this be good solution?