# Apply hash pattern to polygon in openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I have tried to figure out a way to apply advanced fill style to polygons in OpenLayers-3. I would like to find a way to reproduce the following style with OL3:

[Apply hash pattern to polygon in openlayers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398028/apply-hash-pattern-to-polygon-in-openlayers)

http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/ossipoff/openlayers/examples/graphicfill.html

The OL2 solution uses the SLD format, which does not seem to be implemented in OL3.

I have found a great article from boundless geo discussing the geometry option of ol.style.Style that allows to provide advanced styling. This option is great, but applying a hash pattern to a polygon using this technique would heavily impact performance.

http://boundlessgeo.com/2015/04/geometry-based-styling-openlayers-3/

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet supported but see https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2208 for a proposal

Comment: Not quite the answer I was hoping for, but thanks Bart!